# IE page layout breaking randomly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal

I'm looking for some feedback as to why my page layout is breaking in IE on a Drupal site I'm working with (**http://www.shadygrovefertility.com**). My bigger issue is that I can't consistently reproduce the error - given several reloads of the page, about 50% of the time the page will render correctly.

What happens is that a div called "home-content-container" is being bumped down on occasion. That div is supposed to align left beside another div ("sidenav"). Different IE versions have all displayed this behavior for me seemingly at random and I can confirm this testing via Litmus as well (using their page testing service). I also can't replicate the behavior in any other browsers, also confirmed via Litmus. Any ideas as to what is happening?

Might be a stupid/simple fix, but the answer is eluding me right now and I'd appreciate any help with this! I did try searching here and elsewhere but I'm thinking I might not be searching for the correct issue.

Comment: Below are some images of exactly what is happening:
ie broken image - **http://i59.tinypic.com/2w7lv6a.jpg**,

ie working - **http://i59.tinypic.com/30ifaqw.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

to:

You are telling IE to use the IE 7 engine, from 2006 time frame.

BTW, my ex-wife and I went to Shady Grove back in the IE 7 era :)